# Windows - "Get-WindowsFeature" Multiple Devices

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, powershell, configuration-managment

Is there a good methodology for determining if a specific windows feature is enabled across multiple computers?

I know what feature I'm looking for, but I want to generate at minimum a dump of which PCs have it on or off. I do have System Center Configuration Manager available, but don't see the info there if it's present.

Answer (score 1):

From the post
[Ouput Server Name Along With InstallState of Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52627421/ouput-server-name-along-with-installstate-of-service)
comes this snippet of PowerShell code:

```
$serversall = (Get-Content ".\Servers.txt")
$output = @()
foreach($vm in $serversall) { 
  $installed = (Get-WindowsFeature Web-Server -ComputerName $vm).InstallState
  $output += New-Object PSCustomObject -Property @{'ComputerName'=$vm; 'Status'=$installed }
}

$output | Export-Csv -path E:\Scripts\Output\IISWebServersStatus.csv -Append
```